# Which one sounds better, gained or obtained in the given sentence?

Tags: word-usage

> The teacher's causal attribution for a child's behavior [ gained / obtained ] by filtering the child's behavior through his subjective perception of the child's characteristics may determine or influence his behavior toward the child, which, in turn, may affect the development of the child's behavior.

Which of the two is correct, gained or obtained?  Could you help me clarify it?  Thank you always.

Comment: The sentence is written in a very abstract and roundabout manner and is so far removed from normal idiomatic spoken language that there is no need to worry about which word sounds better there, "gained" or "obtained".  **attributions** are neither **gained** nor **obtained**.

Comment: Teachers make biased, subjective judgments about a child's behavior and in so doing they may influence or even determine that behavior.